# How to find Bucketkey for BIM360 Docs files?

Tags: autodesk-data-management

i am attempting to find the true file size as suggested by response at previous [inquiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490529/how-to-get-real-size-of-autodesk-composite-design-from-autodesk-data-management).

The response says to use  GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents to find the hub_id and file_id of files on the BIM 360 docs hub.

Whevener I use the bucket id as retrieved from GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents the message is returned "Bucket not found"

How to find the bucket_id of files on BIM 360 docs?

For example, this is how my file information reads at GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents

```
"type": "items",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:9tyhLmL0Q0--a3otlFxQZw",
            "attributes": {
                "displayName": "EQIX-BIM360 TEST-GH_R20.rvt",
                "createTime": "2021-02-24T02:33:25.0000000Z",
                "createUserId": "9EW2J6HXXX7M",
                "createUserName": "Mario Lopez",
                "lastModifiedTime": "2021-02-24T02:33:48.0000000Z",
                "lastModifiedUserId": "9EW2J6HP9R7M",
                "lastModifiedUserName": "Mario Lopez",
                "hidden": false,
                "reserved": false,
                "extension": {
                    "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel",
                    "version": "1.0.0",
                    "schema": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel-1.0.0"
                    },
                    "data": {}
```

Which part of the above data is to be used as the bucketKey and objectKey for GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey/details, in order to get the true file  size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're omitting the required part of the response from [GET folder contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) on your question.

Keep in mind that you'll need to get the id from `included/relationships/storage/data/id` of a specific file version, as you can find [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/#example).

With this id obtained, please refer [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document/#step-5-create-a-storage-object) to understand better how you can retrieve the bucketKey.

You can also find it under `included/relationships/storage/meta/href`, but in this case, you'll find the value as `"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/<bucket key>/objects/...`

Comment: @jJoãoMartins,

Thank you.

I looked further down and found the required part I was omitting.

With the id obtained I found that the version attributes storageSize and the size of OSS>Get Object Details both do not tell the true size of the file.

These numbers are the aggregate size  of  the file when all links are combined.